# How to join table to table created from query

Tags: sql, join

I query to get the top 5 results of IPs and then i want to get for each IP, the countries and others fields related to it by join.

```
select actual_ip, actual_country_code, actual_country_name, organization  FROM "public"."bus_request" inner join (
    select top 5 actual_ip, count(*) FROM "public"."bus_request" 
    where app_name = 'xxxxx' and request_score>0 and date >= '2019-06-07' and event_type <> 'browser_js' 
    group by actual_ip order by count desc ) as temp on  actual_ip = temp.actual_ip

SQL Error [500310] [42702]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column reference "actual_ip" is ambiguous;
```

Comment: you have columns with the same name(`actual_ip`) in two tables. You should explicitly tell from which table to use colum `select "public"."bus_request"."actual_ip"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which DBMS you're using, but try resolving the ambiguity by specifying the table, e.g.:

```
select busreq.actual_ip, actual_country_code, actual_country_name, organization  FROM "public"."bus_request" as busreq inner join (
    select top 5 actual_ip, count(*) FROM "public"."bus_request" 
    where app_name = 'xxxxx' and request_score>0 and date >= '2019-06-07' and event_type <> 'browser_js' 
    group by actual_ip order by count desc ) as temp on busreq.actual_ip = temp.actual_ip
```

(you may need to disambiguate the inner use of `actual_ip` - but hopefully not.)

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* qualify all column references in a query that references more than one table.  In addition, you should use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
select br.actual_ip, br.actual_country_code, br.actual_country_name, br.organization
from "public"."bus_request" br inner join
     (select top 5 br2.actual_ip, count(*) 
      from "public"."bus_request" br2
      where br2.app_name = 'xxxxx' and
            br2.request_score > 0 and
            br2.date >= '2019-06-07' and
            br2.event_type <> 'browser_js' 
      group by br2.actual_ip
      order by count(*) desc
     ) br2
     on br2.actual_ip = br.actual_ip;
```